# Selenium webdriver how to get text value just after img tag

Tags: selenium

Here is my HTML code

```
 <div id="sucessmessage" class="confirmmessage">
        <img src="/QA_TEST/OURTEST/success.gif" alt="">
        New Customer Successfully Created
    </div>
```

How I try to get text value of "New Customer Successfully Created"

```
String myxapth = "//*[@id='successMessage']/img";

String myvalue1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(myxapth)).getText();
String myvalue2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(myxapth)).getAttribute("value") ;
```

System result as below
myvalue1 is null
myvalue2 is null

Comment: what do you mean by just after image tag? sibling node, child node, parent node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with following code,

```
String text=driver.findElement(By.Id("successMessage").getText();
System.out.println("text value is" + text);
```

Comment: @Murthi no doubt your provided answer is correct and helpful but only answer is not good enough. I think OP is fresher and you need to provide some explanation, document link that could help him and other fresher to understand better for future..Thanks..:)

Comment: Sure, I will do that in future. may i know who is OP?

Comment: @Murthi [OP stands for Original Poster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean)... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath-

```
String myxapth = "//*[@id="sucessmessage"]";
String myvalue1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(myxapth)).getText();
```